# method with catched SqlJetException throws a SqlJetException after executing

Tags: java, exception

I have a `Database` and a `Control` Class. The `Database class` makes the access to the SQLite database easier by providing methods for creating the SQLite Database and inserting Data and such. Those methods may be throwing a SqlJetException which is handled in every method.

The `Control class` is calling those methods from the `Database class`, but complains that SqlJetException is not caught. I personally estimate a SqlJetException handling in the `Control class` as bad object oriented design, so I want to avoid that.

**My Question** is why do my Database methods throw Exceptions although I have caught them? And how can I fix that?

**Error Log**

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ voc ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/toogley/src/voc/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/toogley/src/voc/src/main/java/voc/Control.java:[14,23] error: unreported exception SqlJetException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[ERROR] /home/toogley/src/voc/src/main/java/voc/Control.java:[15,25] error: unreported exception SqlJetException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[ERROR] /home/toogley/src/voc/src/main/java/voc/Control.java:[16,21] error: unreported exception SqlJetException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[ERROR] /home/toogley/src/voc/src/main/java/voc/Control.java:[20,21] error: unreported exception SqlJetException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Database Class:**

```
package voc;

import org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.*;
import org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.ISqlJetTable;
import org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb;

import java.io.File;

public class Database {
    private SqlJetDb db;

    public void createNew() throws SqlJetException {
        File dbFile = new File("db.sqlite");
        dbFile.delete();

        try {
            db = SqlJetDb.open(dbFile, true);
            db.getOptions().setAutovacuum(true);
            db.beginTransaction(SqlJetTransactionMode.WRITE);

            db.getOptions().setUserVersion(1);
        } catch (SqlJetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.commit();
        }
    }

    public void createTable() throws SqlJetException {
        try {
            db.beginTransaction(SqlJetTransactionMode.WRITE);

            db.createTable("voc");
            db.createIndex("english-term");
            db.createIndex("german-translation");

        } catch (SqlJetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.commit();
        }
    }

    public void setData(String englishVoc, String germanTranslation) throws SqlJetException {
        try {
            db.beginTransaction(SqlJetTransactionMode.WRITE);

            ISqlJetTable table = db.getTable("voc");
            table.insert(englishVoc, germanTranslation);

        } catch (SqlJetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.commit();
        }
    }

    public String getData(String s) throws SqlJetException {
        String returnVal = "";
        try {
            db.beginTransaction(SqlJetTransactionMode.READ_ONLY);

            ISqlJetTable table = db.getTable("voc");
            returnVal = table.lookup(s).toString();
        } catch (SqlJetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.commit();
        }
    return returnVal;
    }
```

**Control Class**

```
package voc;

public class Control {

    private Database theDB;

    public Control() {
        theDB = new Database();
    }

    public void fillDB() {
        theDB.createNew(); // <<< SqlJetException
        theDB.createTable(); // <<< SqlJetException
        theDB.setData("mobility", "Ortsunabhängigkeit"); // <<< SqlJetException
    }

    public void receiveData() {
        theDB.getData("test"); // <<< SqlJetException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch all of them, it is no longer true that your method throws SqlJetException, and you should remove that part of your method signatures.

The compiler does not actually understand this situation, when you declare that your method throws this and that checked exception, the compiler does not check any further if it is true or not. Only the opposite is caught, when your code actually may throw a checked exception, and it is neither caught nor declared in the method signature, you will get an error message from the compiler.